# Triple integral limits in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

In the tripple integral to calculate the volume of a sphere 
why does setting the limits as follows not work?

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}
\int_{0}^{R} p^2 \sin{\phi}
\, dp\,d\theta\,d\phi $$

Comment: You've assigned the wrong bounds to the wrong integral. From your integrand, we should have $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account my comment:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^R \rho^2\sin\phi\, d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta=2\pi\int_0^\pi\left.\frac13\rho^3\right|_0^R\sin\phi\,d\phi=$$

$$\frac{2\pi R^3}3\int_0^\pi\sin\phi\,d\phi=\frac{2\pi R^3}3(-\cos\phi|_0^\pi)=\frac{4\pi R^3}3$$

It looks like working fine to me...Perhaps, as Michael points out in the comments, your problem is because you had the wrong limits for the variables? It is $\;0\le \theta\le2\pi\;,\;\;0\le\phi\le\pi\;,\;\;0\le\rho\le R\;$

Comment: You've switched the order of integration without switching the bounds, which is why you're getting the right answer. The issue with the original asker is that they've assigned the wrong bounds to the wrong variable.

Comment: @MichaelLee That's because I copied from the OP and it's a little typo, easily corrected....and yes: perhaps the problem he has is because the confusion between variables and theire limits. Good catch, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jacobian is p^2sin(ϕ). If you integrate from 0 to 2pi in ϕ you are going through a point in which the Jacobian is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R>0$ be the radius of the sphere $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\vert x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=R^{2}\}$. You want to compute the volume of $B=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\vert x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\le R^{2}\}$.

You can do it using cartesian coordinates, which requires more work and calculation. But you can also try to convert these coordinates into the so-called spherical coordinates. As you should know, if you switch to spherical coordinates, you get the factor $\rho^{2}\sin(\phi)$ called the "[Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)".

The volume of a certain region of the space is obtained by taking the integral of $1$ over this region. This fact can be intuitively understood when looking for the area of a region in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: a very simple example is the area of the rectangle $\mathcal{R}:=[x_{a},x_{b}]\times[y_{c},y_{d}]$ where $x_{a}<x_{b}$ and $y_{c}<y_{d}$. We know from basic geometry that its area is $(x_{b}-x_{a})(y_{d}-y_{c})$. But with integrals, it is obtained as follows:

\begin{align*}
\text{Area}(\mathcal{R})&=\int_{\mathcal{R}}1\text{d}\sigma\\
&=\int_{x_{a}}^{x_{b}}\int_{y_{c}}^{y_{d}}1\text{d}y\text{d}x\\
&=\int_{x_{a}}^{x_{b}}(y_{d}-y_{c})\text{d}x\\
&=(y_{d}-y_{c})\int_{x_{a}}^{x_{b}}1\text{d}x\\
&=(x_{b}-x_{a})(y_{d}-y_{c})
\end{align*}

This is true for any system of coordinates as long as we take the Jacobian (associated with the said system) into account. It is how we obtain:

$$\text{Vol}(B)=\color{magenta}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\color{limegreen}{\int_{0}^{\pi}}\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{R}}1\cdot\overbrace{\rho^{2}\sin(\phi)}^{\text{the Jacobian}}\color{blue}{\text{d}\rho}\color{limegreen}{\text{d}\phi}\color{magenta}{\text{d}\theta}$$

And the calculations are given in the other answers.

[image]

Comment: But how does switching the limits of $ \theta $ and $ \phi $ make a difference?

Comment: @Joseph This makes a huge difference because of the Jacobian! Do you know why spherical coordinates actually work? I mean, why $x=\rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),\,y=\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\,z=\rho\cos(\phi)$? This is "easily" obtained by trigonometry in rectangle triangles but it has an important impact on the Jacobian. I invite you to read the Wikipedia pages about these concepts (Jacobian & spherical coordinates) if what I say in this comment is not clear to you. I may add it to my answer as well, if you want.